# Zend_Translate: not string, but ID based translation - or how to handle changes in original string

Tags: php, zend-framework, translation, zend-translate

As far as I understood, Zend_Translate uses strings as keys for translation files. This means that if I change the original string (e.g. fix some typo), all translations for this string will be lost.

Is there a way to update those translations automatically? My idea is to mark those translations as "TODO" when the original string has changed.

To achieve this, I guess I have to use an ID based translation system instead of a string based translation system. Every string has a unique ID.

I know that a string based translation system has the advantage that equal strings do not have to be translated twice. This is a very rare use case in my application, so translation equal strings twice would be absolutely fine.

I thought of implementing this myself, but I don't know how to do it with good performance.

Any suggestions on this? Can Zend_Translate handle changes in the original string? Are there other translation systems that can handle this use case?

Answer (score 0):

This can't be handled automatically. At least not easily. (it might be done with code analysis, code generation, etc.). We used "stubs" for translation - `$this->translate('please-register') // Please register.` Works fine, but adds more work for developers - they need to create translation files even for the native language. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This does not work in our use case, though, since the user defines the sentences that will later be translated. We will probably develop our own system that relies on a database table where the primary keys are strings made up of concatenated table IDs (the whole hierarchy down from the user's project ID to the table where the text is in) and the column name of the text we want to translate. I hope that telling MySQL to use a Hash for the translations database table provide sufficient speed. I'd warmly welcome any other approach.

Comment: It's really hard to help you without concrete example :( I still can understand what you try to translate. Page UI? Or user input?